# How to integrate Go.js's floorplan with React.js

Tags: reactjs, gojs

I wanted to create a react project allowing a user to annotate floorplan thanks to Go.js's floorplanner here is the link https://gojs.net/latest/projects/floorplanner/FloorPlanner.html. If you look visit that link and down below you will see the scripts that were used to create floorplanner. But instead of creating the floorplanner with vanilla JS I wanted to use React.js. Can someone help with the integration of Go.js's floorplanner with React?

Comment: @WalterNorthwoods, pls can you help)))

Comment: @SimonSarris, pls can you help)))

Answer (score 0):

This question is too vague for an easy answer. You should look at the react example: https://github.com/NorthwoodsSoftware/gojs-react

And modify it to your liking. This can involve taking large parts of all of the floor planner sample, though if you have no practice with GoJS this it may be worth taking the time to learn everything involved in the sample, before any integration.

Comment: hi Simon)) yeah I have visited the link you provided and you can kill me but I what to start with :D, that is, ok I have installed gojs-react and used the code being provided in gojs-react website that you provided. But, I saw boxes with arrows. But I want to integrate floorplanner into React. Ok, then I opened floorplan.js and saw truckload of code))) which made me lost. Therefore, pls can you give a hint since I admit, I have no idea of converting floorplan.js's code into React code))

Comment: or do you recommend using vanilla js with floorplanner instead of React?

Comment: The floor planner sample is just several GoJS templates, settings, and custom tools wrapped into one demo. It is a large sample to start from. It might be better if you use it as a guide to make your own floor planner. We also have smaller samples that have floor-plan-like elements, that are easier to learn from when you are starting out: https://gojs.net/latest/samples/planogram.html

Comment: ok and Simon, can I, say, integrate planogram and other appropriate diagrams one by one like lego blocks to React by using gojs-react?